# Ways to not clog the CPU load

Tags: c#, cpu-usage

I believe that if I write a program that uses a `while(1){...}` and run it, it will make the CPU load go to 100% (is this true? I ve done this and that happened). Also I believe that perhaps when writing a TCP program, when using a blocking Connect function, that will happens as well.

How about `ManualResetEvent` and `WaitOne()`?? And what happens with the `ThreadSleep()` function? Will this also clog the CPU??

I have the following code skeleton:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
    {

        class Program
         {
         private static volatile bool keepRunning = true;
         private static System.Threading.ManualResetEvent connectDone = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);

         static void Main(string[] args)
            {
              while(keepRunning)
                 {

                  //Here some code to create a socket client

                  try
                    {
                        connectDone.Reset();  //not signaled

                        Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect...");
                        clientSocket.BeginConnect("127.0.0.1", 4242, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), clientSocket);

                        //wait here until the callback processes the connection

                        connectDone.WaitOne();  //<---HERE!!!

                        //Some more other code
                     }
                   catch(Exception e)
                    {
                      Console.WriteLine("Error");
                    }

                    //Here do some more processing and eventually

                     if (clientSocket.Connected)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Closing the socket");
                        clientSocket.Close();
                     }
                }
         }//Main

          //The callback for asynchronous connect
            private static void OnConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    //retrieve the client from the state object
                    TcpClient clientSocket = (TcpClient)ar.AsyncState;

                    //complete the connection
                    clientSocket.EndConnect(ar);

                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully Connected");

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error on End Connect: {0}", e.Message);

                }
                finally
                {
                    connectDone.Set();
                }
            }



      }
    }
```

The code is not complete but basically uses asynchronous connect. What I would like to ask is 1) will this clog the CPU 2) specially in the HERE!!! part  will WaitOne clog the CPU? What is the impact of WaitOne in resources use?

How about if I use (different code) ThreadSleep? Will this impact the CPU load?

---

(I ask this not of intellectual curiosity but because I am having a problem of CPU using 100% resources only when running a program in one computer and yet not in other- is basically the program above when the connection fails. - on success there is no clog)

Comment: This code will degrade very poorly when the connection attempt fails.  It uses local-loopback so it isn't slowed down at all by the network.  It instantly tries to re-connect, the odds that the second attempt will work are *very* close to zero.  And so on, and so on, burning core until somebody notices a screenful of error messages and does something to make port 4242 available.  It needs a better fallback, not using try-catch-em-all exception handling would be better for example.  Or making louder noise.  Or delaying for at least several minutes before trying again.

Comment: Thanks. I got the first part, but not the second: " It needs a better fallback, not using try-catch-em-all exception handling would be better for example. " what would be better? How can make louder noise?  The reason why this is like this is because the server can start at any moment and the client has to be ready- according to the requirements

Answer (score 1):

A blocking call to [`Socket.Connect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7ew360f(v=vs.110).aspx) does not "clog up" the CPU, because the thread is sleeping, waiting for the I/O operation to complete. In fact, This is the case with pretty much all I/O operations, not just opening a socket. If all you're worried about is CPU load - then there's no need to go for asynchronous I/O.

The same can be said about [`ManualResetEvent.WaitOne`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.waitone(v=vs.110).aspx). In fact, what you're doing there by waiting is essentially converting the asynchronous I/O back into synchronous (blocking).

The reason why `while(true)`, causes CPU load is because instead of waiting for a signal to wake up from sleep, the thread is instead actively checking for the completion of an operation, performing work - it's in a [spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock). This can be remedied by allowing the thread to sleep a bit in the cycle. Although you'd be better off not creating spinlocks at all, and going for other synchronization methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It certainly clarified my thoughts that are very disorganized now. I have two questions: 1) I realized that I basically converted the asynchronous into synchronous. So is there anywhere an example of >asynchronous operation in a console (not windows) application?  and 2) I wonder why my program is getting 100% CPU in one computer- certainly not on my development PC